# How do I release this connector

Tags: electrical, lighting

House was built in 1982 and this is a connector going to my 2x2 florescent light fixtures in the drop ceiling. How do they come apart or off? The small tab on the left was connected but broke from becoming fragile. Also what are these connections called?[image: blue connector]

Comment: It's not a connector. It's a strain relief gasket clamped around MN-B (Romex) cable going into the fixture.

Comment: You need to open up the enclosure and deal with the romex connections within.

Comment: BTW, get a replacement strain relief appropriate for regional codes; compression type are likely to break on removal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to squeeze the two tabs that are holding it in the hole, either from the other side of the sheet metal or by pressing a small screwdriver against the tabs from the side you see, alternating sides until it comes loose.

[See page 2 of this PDF for removal instructions](https://assetcloud.roccommerce.net/files/_smcelectric/7/1/6/idw_document_69a3b8bcec22d8dd6b47d86e8c8818cf86b596071612f71a129ade3e1f86e7ae.pdf).

The manufacturer calls it a non-metallic cable connector.